# Select intent not triggered if selection is not immediately followed by carousel

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, dialogflow-es, api-ai

I am facing a problem with listening to User Selection when we show a carousel. We are using askWithCarousel with dialogFlow and listening to click of a carousel item using `actions_intent_option` event. When a carousel is displayed to user, assistant starts listening to user input using mic, if mic gets a random input from user (which doesn’t match any of our synonyms for the carousel items) and then the user taps on any carousel item or says any of the synonyms, `actions_intent_option` event is not getting fired. It works fine if this interaction is immediately followed by showing of carousel. Else, it will take carousel title as user input and resolves to a different intent.

Not able to get the id of the carousel item because of this. Is there a way to disable mic or emit `actions_intent_option` even when the user clicks on carousel item later. Please help with this flow.

Answer (score 1):

Selection events are only emitted, as you've discovered, right after the carousel or list has been sent to the user.

I'd recommend setting up a fallback intent to check for the titles of the list items or prompting the user with a carousel or list again.

Comment: Thank you @matthewayne. Even I thought of the same work around for now